# Failing to select Radio button value with Cypress

Tags: reactjs, cypress

I am trying to select Radio button's(react-radio-buttons) value with Cypress.
But it doesn't seem to work.

Here is my code:

```
<Radio
  value={this.state.input.radio}
  onChange={(value) => this.updateInput("radio", value)}
  horizontal
  className="radioGroup"
  data-cy="radioButton"
>
  <RadioButton
    value="1"
    iconSize={20}
    padding={-1}
  ></RadioButton>
  <p>Yes</p>
  <RadioButton
    value="0"
    iconSize={20}
    padding={-1}
  ></RadioButton>
  <p>No</p>
</Radio>;
```

I am trying to access and change values using data-cy with this code:

So far this line of test is working:

```
cy.get("[data-cy=radioButton]").first().click()
```

But it doesn't change the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `data-cy` attribute is on the `<Radio>` not the `<RadioButton>`. I would expect that you need to navigate down to the child elements and click one of them - although `cy.get("[data-cy=radioButton]").first().click()` is working, so I'm not seeing the complete picture.

You have `onChange={(value) => this.updateInput("radio", value)}`, so you probably need to trigger a change event as well.

Try

```
cy.get("[data-cy=radioButton]")
  .children()
  .first()
  .click()
  .trigger('change');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with forcing the command:

```
cy.get("[data-cy=radioButton]").first().click({force:true})
```

Comment: Why force:true?

Comment: @NankerPhelge elge Because with force: true doesn't check if element is clickable or visible or covered by another element, it will click it instantly without check.

Comment: Ok, but it's not any of those things?

Comment: @NankerPhelge the locator is not correct, Try  cy.get("[value="1"]").first().click({force:true}) if you want to select Yes radio button.

Comment: So is it visibility or wrong locator, or is it just a guess?

Answer (score 0):

Your selector is not correct, if you want to click on Yes button you should use this code, for No just change the value to 0:

```
  cy.get('[value="1"]').click({force:true})
```